# Spring restart end point using spring cloud context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, endpoint

I am trying to programmatically restart my spring boot application end point. Below is the lines I have used.

```
public class FileWatcher {
    @Autowired
    private RestartEndpoint restartEndpoint;

    public void onFileChange() {
        Thread restartThread = new Thread(() -> restartEndpoint.restart());
        restartThread.setDaemon(false);
        restartThread.start();
    }
}
```

But it throws the below error.

```
Error:(32, 64) java: cannot access org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint
  class file for org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint not found
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the actuator starter?

Comment: sorry didn't get that :( I am new to spring

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready

Add the actuator dependencies, in maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

For Gradle, use the declaration:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
}
```